# Sites network with sub-folders

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I want to create sites network. I was following with this tutorial: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
Unfortunately it doesn't works. I the admin panel I do not have any links to manage the sites like 'Network admin': http://codex.wordpress.org/images/7/78/network-admin-link.png

My wordpress is here: k-state|dot|zxq|dot|net

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What wp version you using?

Comment: Also, that page has now been updated to include screenshots from the *current* version of WordPress (3.3) to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake...I change wp-config.php adding lines at the end, insetead of add them before /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just noticed your answer (disregard my revision).

Answer (score 0):

**Have you added this to the wp-config file?**

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

**Do you have multiple WordPress Installations on your server?**

...........................................................................................

...........................................................................................

.

.

## **ADDITIONAL *(revised)* ANSWER**

If you're not against using a plug-in, you can try this one:
[Multi-site Enabler Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-multi-site-enabler-plugin-v10/)

Let me know if you're against using the plug-in and I'll help you troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Yes I added it and I have only one WordPress on my server.

Comment: See my revision.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your network first. Click tools. You can see one submenu to create your network